# spawn EACCESS Error while running / building Android Platform on Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

As many users, i had this error when doing

```
ionic cordova run android -android
```

or

```
cordova build android --verbose
```

the output :

```
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /Users/davidanquetin/GIT/MEDIATOOLS/DOMME/domme-app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "Domme" to /Users/davidanquetin/GIT/MEDIATOOLS/DOMME/domme-app/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml
Wrote out Android package name "com.pasquet.domme.all" to /Users/davidanquetin/GIT/MEDIATOOLS/DOMME/domme-app/platforms/android/src/com/pasquet/domme/all/MainActivity.java
Updating icons at platforms/android/res
Updating splash screens at platforms/android/res
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Running command: /usr/libexec/java_home 
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/davidanquetin/Documents/_UTILITAIRES/TECHNIQUE/android-sdk-macosx/
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.0-milestone-1/bin/gradle" -p /Users/davidanquetin/GIT/MEDIATOOLS/DOMME/domme-app/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/davidanquetin/GIT/MEDIATOOLS/DOMME/domme-app/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
Error: spawn EACCES
```

i tried many manipulations founded on the web (chmod etc...) but nothing is working..

when i try

```
chmod +x /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.0-milestone-1/bin/gradle
```

i have :

```
chmod + /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.0-milestone-1/bin/gradle
```

and always the same error after building...

thanks for ideas !

**UPDATE / RESOLVED**

The way i resolved the problem :

- delete Android Studio app
- redownload and reinstall it
- update java
- creating a new ionic project, then update it with my previous assets / code files.
- reinstall platforms with a clean installation

and...it works !
I think it is manly Android Studio removing and reinstallation which resolves the problem.

If it could help !

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer not as an edit..

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE / RESOLVED**

The way i resolved the problem :

- delete Android Studio app

  - redownload and reinstall it
  - update java
  - creating a new ionic project, then update it with my previous assets
    / code files.
  - reinstall platforms with a clean installation

and...it works ! I think it is manly Android Studio removing and reinstallation which resolves the problem.

If it could help !